# MKOverlayView Coordinate System

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview

From within a MKOverlayView - how can I convert a Lat Lon value in to the MKOverlayViews coordinate System?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation?

```
Converting Points on the Map:

    – pointForMapPoint:
    – mapPointForPoint:
    – rectForMapRect:
    – mapRectForRect:
```

From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I have looked at the docs - however these methods don't get me the answer. It appears that there is a large scale factor being applied. MapPointForPoint(0, 0) returns (<giant_x>, <giant y>). MapPointForPoint(100, 100) returns (<gian_x> + 100, <giant_y> + 100). If I draw that line, it's so small it is not even visible.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple really. Just divide by zoomScale. Apparently I am suffering from end of day syndrome.